# How did physicists conclude that 98% of mass is due to the strong force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, mass, mass-energy, strong-force

On a video on YouTube called 'weak and strong nuclear force (9/15)' at 0:55 a scientist said that 98% of mass is due to the strong force.

Comment: Here's a video that explains it in Layman's terms.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ztc6QPNUqls

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the mass of the hadrons, it is because of the energy/mass contributed by the gluons carrying the SNF and virtual quarks and antiquarks, which is high compared the three valance quarks. The valance quarks are the three "permanent" quarks that we think make up the proton and neutron. The Higgs field has a much lower effect on the mass of these particles than the effect described  above.  I am not sure about the 98 percent figure though.

[image]

From  [Wikipedia Hadrons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadron)

> Hadrons, however, are not composed of just three or two quarks, because of the strength of the strong force. More accurately, strong force gluons have enough energy (E) to have resonances composed of massive (m) quarks (E > mc2) . Thus,virtual quarks and antiquarks, in a 1:1 ratio, form the majority of massive particles inside a hadron. The two or three quarks are the excess of quarks vs. antiquarks in hadrons, and vice versa in anti-hadrons. Because the virtual quarks are not stable wave packets (quanta), but irregular and transient phenomena, it is not meaningful to ask which quark is real and which virtual; only the excess is apparent from the outside. Massless virtual gluons compose the numerical majority of particles inside hadrons.